# how to configure firewalld, port-forward to specific VM:port and permit VM to external

Tags: port-forwarding, linux-kvm, firewalld

I have KVM/libvirt env as follows.

```
   em1(external)
      |
   bridge0
  /   |   \
VM1  VM2  VM3
```

I hope to access to VM1(192.168.122.103) with 9091  port from external with following.

```
# firewall-cmd --zone=external --add-forward-port=port=9091:proto=tcp:toport=9091:toaddr=192.168.122.103 --permanent
```

It works properly as expected.
However, internal  VM cannot use external DNS and ping.

Hence, I setup following.

```
# firewall-cmd --permanent --direct --passthrough ipv4 -I FORWARD -i bridge0 -j ACCEPT 
# firewall-cmd --permanent --direct --passthrough ipv4 -I FORWARD -o bridge0 -j ACCEPT
```

As a result, internal VM can communicate to external with DNS and ping.
However, port-forwarding doesn't work.

How do I setup port-forwarding and internal VM communication to external?